# Multiplication algorithm in SPARC

Tags: assembly, multiplication, sparc

been working for a few (straight) days on this multiplication algorithm in SPARC... Really can't figure out what's wrong. I've stepped through a few iterations of the code. It's doing what the proposed C algorithm wants it to. Here it is in C

```
negative = multiplier >= 0 ? 0 : 1;
product = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    if (multiplier & 1)
        product += multiplicand;
(product and multiplier registers combined as a unit) >> 1;
}
if (negative)
    product -= multiplicand;
```

And here it is in SPARC Assembly, note I haven't implemented functionality for negative numbers yet. The program runs the proposed number of times. So the loop is not the issue. I think my problem may be how I am accounting for the right shift across two 32 bit registers, which currently is just (in Psuedo-code)

sra small register 1
if (rightmost bit of large register = 1)
     change leftmost bit of small register to a 1
sra larger register

But it doesn't seem to be working out as planned, as I am getting really wonky numbers

Here's the whole program in SPARC... any help you guys could offer would be appreciated.

```
 fmt:   .asciz "Multiplicand: %d, Product: %8.8X%8.8X Counter: %d\n"            !output statement
.align 4                !align formatting

.global main
main:   save     %sp, -96, %sp
set     82732983, %l0       !move multiplicand into register %l0
set     120490892, %l1      !move multiplier into register %l1
set     0, %l2          !initialize product variable at 0
set     1, %l3          !initialize counter variable to 1
ba  test
mov     32, %l5         !put max loop value in a register

loop:
set     fmt, %o0        !setup the format string for the print statement
mov     %l0, %o1        !moving variables for printing
mov     %l1, %o2
mov     %l2, %o3
mov %l3, %o4
call    printf
nop
postprint:
    and     %l1, 1, %l6     !bitwise and between multiplier and 1, store result in %l6
cmp     %l6, 0          !comparison statement comparing the above to 1
be  else            !skip the addition if rightmost bit of multiplier is 0
nop

add     %l0, %l2, %l2       !adding multiplicand and product
sra     %l1, 1, %l1     !shifting multiplier right
and     1, %l2, %l6     !checking if rightmost bit of product is a 1
cmp     %l6, 1          !conditional statement to check this
bl  endif           !if it's not a one, branch to zero
nop             !non op

clr     %o4
set 0x40000000, %o4     !put 0x40000000 in a register
or      %l1,    %o4,    %l1 !if it is a one, bitwise do or with 0x40000000 to make a one in the leftmost bit of the multiplier
    sra     %l2,    1,  %l2     !shift product to the right by 1
    inc     %l3         !increment counter variable
    ba      test            !and branch to the testing statement
    nop

endif:
clr     %o5
sra     %l2, 1, %l2     !arithmetic shift product right by one (first line of endif)
inc     %l3         !increment counter variable
ba  test            
nop
else:
    sra     %l1, 1, %l1     !shift multiplier to the right
    and     %l2, 1, %l6     !check if rightmost bit of product is 1
    cmp     %l6, 1          !conditional statement to check this
    bl      endif           !branch to endif if it's not
    nop             !nop
clr     %o4
set 0x40000000, %o4     !put 0x40000000 in a register
    or      %l1, %o4, %l1       !if the rightmost bit is one, we use a bitwise or to place a 1 in the leftmost bit of the multiplier
    sra     %l2, 1, %l2     !then right arithmetic shift the product
    inc     %l3         !and increment the counter
    ba      test
    nop

test:   cmp     %l3, %l5
    bl      loop


done:   mov 1,  %g1             !Exit the program
    ta  0
```

Comment: If that wants to be everyday common multiplication, then not even the C/pseudo code is right. You can test it for the simple case of x*1, it will return x/2.

Answer (score 0):

Split the functionality as: `Add()`and `Multiply()`

[SPARC Assembly manual](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~atkinson/teaching/sp05/259/sparc.pdf)

[Addition Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition)

```
unsigned int Add(unsigned int num1, unsigned int num2)
{
    /* Iterate till there is no carry  */
    while (num2 != 0)
    {
        /* carry now contains common set bits of num1 and num2  */
        unsigned int carry = num1 & num2;  

        /* Sum of bits of numbers where at least one of the bits is not set */
        num1 = num1 ^ num2; 

        /* Carry is shifted by one so that adding it to x gives the required sum */
        num2 = carry << 1;
    }
    return num1;
}
```

[Multiplication Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm)

```
unsigned int Multiply(unsigned int multiplicand, unsigned int multiplier)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;

    while(multiplier != 0) /* Use while instead of for */
    {
        if (multiplier & 0x01) 
        {
            result = Add(result, multiplicand);
        }

        multiplicand <<= 1; /* Left shifting the value contained in 'multiplicand' by 1 */
        multiplier >>=1;    /* Right shifting the value contained in 'multiplier' by 1. */
   }

   return result;
}
```

Please Note: `int` is assumed to be 32bit integer here. (You can replace the function signature according to the `typedefs` present). Also, you can add checks for overflow and handle error accordingly.

Comment: SPARC has an `add` instruction and the question is already using it.  You don't need to emulate `add`, only multiply.

Comment: No, integer `add     %l0, %l2, %l2`.  FPADD32 is obviously floating-point, where this algorithm doesn't work.  (Unless the multiplicand if `float` and the multiplier is `int`).  Also, your algorithm only works for unsigned, or non-negative signed `int`.  A negative multiplier will never become `0` from arithmetic right shifts.

Comment: Agreed, The `multiplicand` can be negative, but the same is not true for `multiplier`. The only way is to repeat addition `n` times? For example:

Comment: Your C function declares it as signed `int`.  That's the problem.

Comment: Surprised that not getting compiler warnings for the conversion even explicitly using ` -Wconversion` flag.